# Stored FUNCTION is not returning result in MySql?

Tags: mysql, function, stored-functions

I have a simple MySql query which successfully returns single value.

```
select tl.tour_log_id 
from tour_log tl
WHERE tl.log = "SUBTOUR_START" 
      AND tl.inquiry_id = 7519618
     and tl.truck_id = 450 and tl.tour_id = 6174
 limit 1; -- tour_log_id -> 736318. Even without limit 1, query gives always single value. This is how database is structured.
```

However, I do have a Mysql `Stored Function`, which is supposed to do the same thing, but I'm getting `null`. I generated this function by doing Right Click on Functions -> Create Function.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getTourLogIdForSubtourStart`( 
     inquiryId int, truckId int, tourId int) RETURNS int
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE tourLogIdSubtourStart int; 
        DECLARE tourLogIdSubtourEnd int;  
        
        select tour_log.tour_log_id into tourLogIdSubtourStart
        from fleaty.tour_log tl
        WHERE tl.log = "SUBTOUR_START" 
              AND tl.inquiry_id = inquiryId
             and tl.truck_id = truckId and tl.tour_id = tourId
         limit 1;    -- 
    
        -- set tourLogIdSubtourEnd = callSomeOtherFunction(tourLogIdSubtourStart, inquiryId, truckId);
         
        -- here will be cursor to process some result set, based on tourLogIdSubtourStart and tourLogIdSubtourEnd
    
        
        
    RETURN  (tourLogIdSubtourStart);
    END
```

This is how I call above function:

```
set @s = getTourLogIdForSubtourStart(7519618, 450, 6174);

select @s;
```

This prints `null`. Why?

Comment: [Edit] the question and add DDL and DML with some sample data for the table so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: As you correctly observe, LIMIT 1 is fine here. But note that in general, LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply put **never** use column names as variable names

> ```
> CREATE tABLE tour_log (tour_log_id int, log varchar(19),inquiry_id BIGint,truck_id int, tour_id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tour_log VALUEs (1,'SUBTOUR_START',7519618, 450, 6174)
> ```

> ```
>   CREATE  FUNCTION `getTourLogIdForSubtourStart`( 
>      _inquiryId int, _truckId int, _tourId int) RETURNS int
>         DETERMINISTIC
>     BEGIN
>         DECLARE tourLogIdSubtourStart int; 
>         DECLARE tourLogIdSubtourEnd int;  
>         
>         select tour_log_id into tourLogIdSubtourStart
>         from tour_log tl
>         WHERE tl.log = "SUBTOUR_START" 
>               AND tl.inquiry_id = _inquiryId
>              and tl.truck_id = _truckId and tl.tour_id = _tourId
>          limit 1;    -- 
>     
>         -- set tourLogIdSubtourEnd = callSomeOtherFunction(tourLogIdSubtourStart, inquiryId, truckId);
>          
>         -- here will be cursor to process some result set, based on tourLogIdSubtourStart and tourLogIdSubtourEnd
>     
>         
>         
>     RETURN  (tourLogIdSubtourStart);
>     END
> ```

> ```
> set @s = getTourLogIdForSubtourStart(7519618, 450, 6174);
>
> select @s;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> | @s |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tour_log
> ```
>
> ```
> tour_log_id | log           | inquiry_id | truck_id | tour_id
> ----------: | :------------ | ---------: | -------: | ------:
>           1 | SUBTOUR_START |    7519618 |      450 |    6174
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30196e613d57c25756cf7136fdd377e0)*

Comment: Thanks nbk. This is my first stored function tho :) I haven't tested it yet. As soon as I do, I'll upwote ofc.